# Running Azure SQL stored procedures as logged in AAD user

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database, connection-string

I'm trying to connect to a SQL database on Azure from a web app in such a way that the currently logged in Azure AD user is passed to the database and the stored procedures are executed by said user rather than by a generic SQL user (which is what we normally do).

Our goal is to be able to use something like `current_user` or `system_user` in our stored procedures to only return rows that a user specifically has access to. That way, the stored procedure doesn't have to trust that the code logic is requesting only what the logged in user should have access to.

**Is this possible?**

It looks like the "ADO.NET (Active Directory integrated authentication) - private endpoint" connection string listed in Azure might be what I need:

```
Server=tcp:mydbserver.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=mydbname;Persist Security Info=False;User ID={your_username};MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Authentication="Active Directory Integrated";
```

I don't want to authenticate as a *specific* user, I want to authenticate as the *currently logged in* user so I removed the username property from the string. So my final connection string looks like this:

```
Server=tcp:mydbserver.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=mydbname;Persist Security Info=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Authentication="Active Directory Integrated";
```

However, attempting to connect this way throws an exception:

> AdalException: The format of the specified domain name is invalid.

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: I would like to do the same. However I believe that it is not straightforward to get this working. One prerequisite for "AD Integrated" authentication is that your organisation's AD and AAD must be federated together. In our case they are not, and the networking team are not going to do that, -- instead they are using a sync process between the two.